# Printing to console removes hyperlinks created already

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I was trying to create a feature to create hyperlinks in the console while the information is added.
While debugging, I noticed that the first hyperlink is succesfully created, but when the next line is printed to console, the hyperlink dissapears.

The code which I use to create the hyperlinks is:

```
String hyperLinkText = "test";
myConsole.printToConsole(test);

String myFile = new File("D:/Test/testFile.txt");
URI location = myFile.toURI();

IFile[] files = project.getWorkspace().getRoot().findFilesForLocationURI(location);

HyperlinkInformation hyperlinkInformation = new HyperlinkInformation(myConsole, myConsole.getDocument().get().length(), hyperLinkText.length());

FileHyperlink fileHyperlink = new FileHyperlink(hyperlinkInformation,
            files[0], 1);

try {
    hyperlinkInformation.getConsole().addHyperlink(fileHyperlink,
    fileHyperlink.getOffset(), fileHyperlink.getLength());
} catch (BadLocationException e) {
   //
}
```

The function `addHyperlink`:

```
public void addHyperlink(IHyperlink hyperlink, int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {
IDocument document = getDocument();
ConsoleHyperlinkPosition hyperlinkPosition = new ConsoleHyperlinkPosition(hyperlink, offset, length);
try {
    document.addPosition(ConsoleHyperlinkPosition.HYPER_LINK_CATEGORY, hyperlinkPosition);
    fConsoleManager.refresh(this);
} catch (BadPositionCategoryException e) {
    ConsolePlugin.log(e);
}
```

}

Is this the normal behaviour or am I missing something?

Comment: Add hyperlinks how? What extension points are you using? Show us some code/

Comment: @greg-449 I do not know if it has anything to do with the fact that the I'm using a  `LinkedBlockingQueue` to send messages to the console

Comment: @greg-449 Anyway, if I just print the messages and create the hyperlinks after it works fine.